# R: How to turn off the autonum feature with set_caption option in flextable

Tags: r, caption, flextable

I'm a relatively new to R and have looked for an answer elsewhere but can't find it.

I'm knitting a flextable to Word.  I want to "turn off" the autonum feature that adds "Table #:" before my caption string if possible.

I've tried a few things including:

```
set_caption(caption = "Study Characteristics by Aim 1 Enrollment Wave",
                                style = "Table Caption")

set_caption(caption = "Study Characteristics by Aim 1 Enrollment Wave",
                                style = "Table Caption",
                                autonum = NULL)

set_caption(caption = "Study Characteristics by Aim 1 Enrollment Wave",
                                style = "Table Caption",
                                autonum = FALSE)
```

The first one adds "Table 1:" to my caption, while the other two remove the "1" so it looks like "Table :" before my caption.  How do I remove the "Table :" ?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I can't even turn off the number with `autonum = NULL` or `autonum = FALSE`.
But I was able to get rid of the "Table :".

You have to run the following code setting before the flextable code.

```
#set the table caption styling
knitr::opts_chunk$set(tab.cap.pre = "", tab.cap.sep = "")
```

Comment: The autonum = NULL or autonum = FALSE won't work on my end as well. But @ct625's suggested workaround is my temporary remedy. Thanks!